# issue in if condition for page navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$( 'li' ).on( 'click', function( event ) {
            console.log("inside music player");
            var projIndex = $(this).index();
            selectedMedia=$(this).text();
            console.log("------"+projIndex);
            console.log("------"+selectedMedia);
            var extension = selectedMedia.substr( (selectedMedia.lastIndexOf('.') +1) );
            console.log("extension-----"+extension);
            if(extension=="mp3" || extension=="wav")
                {
                var musicLink="#musicPlay_page";
                var selectedLink = document.getElementById('mediaLink'); 
                selectedLink.href=musicLink;
                $('#musicPlay_page').add(playMusicList(selectedMedia));
                }                         
            else if(extension=="mp4")
                {
                var videoLink="#videoPlay_page";
                var selectedLink = document.getElementById('mediaLink'); 
                selectedLink.href=videoLink;
                $('#videoPlay_page').add(playVideoList(selectedMedia));
            }

        });
```

In the above code i need to navigate to two different pages depending upon the type of media i select ( mp3 or mp4). if it's mp3 then it shoul navigate to musicPlay page and if it's mp4 it should navigate to videoPlay page.it works well when i click the first file in the list i.e it navigates to other page , but when i click other than first element of list it doesn't navigate to other page but instead it plays the file in the current page itself , please solve this problem.

```
function onsuccess(files) {
        $('#media_list').remove();

        var d='<div id="media_list">';
        d += '<ul data-role="listview" style="list-style: none outside none;padding: 0;">'
            +'<div style="font-weight:bold;color:black;">';
        for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            console.log("File Name is " + files[i].name); // displays file name

            if(files[i].isDirectory == false){      
                d+='<li style="vertical-align: top;">'
                    +'<a href="" id="mediaLink">'
                    +'<img src="/images/musicPlay_logo.jpg" id="musicPlay"/>'
                    +files[i].name
                    +'</a><hr color="black" size =1 width=500></li>';

            }
        }
        d+= '</div>';
        d+= '</ul>';
        d+= '</div>';
        $("#media_content").append(d);
```

}

this the function i used to display the html content which displays list of media files, you can see in the 'a' tag i left href blank so that on click it goes to click function and depending upon the format of the file i clicked it goes to if condition and the page should be opened

Comment: Provide the html you are dealing with.

Comment: what is the output of
console.log("extension-----"+extension) when you click element other than the first one?

Comment: it gives correct extension , it also plays the song , but doesn't go to musicPlay page

Comment: When you are binding the click event on li events, the href is not pointing to any page. It is pointing to some element in the same page
with id = "videoPlay_page" and "musicPlay_page" not any external page, so it will remain in the same page.

Comment: ok ok . Can u suggest what can i do to avoid it . But how is it navigating to other page when i'm clicking on the first element in the list ?

Comment: See if i remove if condition and only try to play mp3 files then it works fine , the problem occurs due to usage of if condition

Comment: As you said the without if condition it works fine with mp3, so there may be a problem with the playVideoList(selectedMedia) function.
Check if it works accordingly.

Comment: yea it works  , if there is a problem only with playing video then if i click on mp3 other than first element it should go to other page , but it isn't working for that too

Comment: Notice: '<a href="" id="mediaLink">'. So more than one <a></a> elements are having the same id. Id is supposed to be unique. Provide unique is for each a element.

Comment: Due to the above reason document.getElementById() looks for only one element. It returns back the first met element, no matter how many elements with same id are present in the page. So, may be thats why only the first element works, but not others.

Comment: so what changes do i need to make . please suggest

Comment: Either use unique id for each <a></a> tag and access them one by one by that id or use a class to access all of of them  at a time.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is really simple. You're using ID's instead of classes. IDs are unique, and no more than 1 element should have the same id. Here you're using the `mediaLink` and `musicPlay` ids multiple times, and JavaScript only finds the first match, since by definition, there shouldn't be more.
Change the ids to classes, which are reusable identifiers, like this:

```
d+='<li style="vertical-align: top;">'
    +'<a href="" class="mediaLink">'
    +'<img src="/images/musicPlay_logo.jpg" class="musicPlay"/>'
    +files[i].name
    +'</a><hr color="black" size =1 width=500></li>';
```

or add something unique to the ID so it does not repeat, such as the loop counter (`i`), shown below:

```
d+='<li style="vertical-align: top;">'
    +'<a href="" id="mediaLink-'+i+'">'
    +'<img src="/images/musicPlay_logo.jpg" id="musicPlay-'+i+'"/>'
    +files[i].name
    +'</a><hr color="black" size =1 width=500></li>';
```

Then alter your click handler to use the class/id instead. Without the relevant HTML code, this is all I can say. If you can provide the HTML code, I might be able to assist you further in altering the handler's code.

Answer (score -3):

instead of if(extension=="mp3" || extension=="wav")

try if(extension.equals("mp3") || extension.equals("wav"))

Comment: `extention` is a string, [JavaScript strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) don't have a `equals` method.

Comment: yea , because the control is going inside if condition , it's only that the new page is not getting loaded for the click on list element other than first element